# How to add suffix to Teechart axis captions?

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, teechart

I want to add suffix to Teechart axis captions. for ex. πc I want to display c at suffix. I want same for Ψ and μ. Is Teechart 4.1 .NET have this functinality?

Thanks and regards,
Abhijit Shelar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the GetAxisLabel event to customize your labels. You'll find examples at Tutorial 4 and the features demo. Both tutorials and demo are available at TeeChart's program group.

Comment: @ Narcis Calvet I want to set Axis Captions or Titles. Is GetAxisLabel event working for Titles?

Comment: @AbhijitShelar no, there's no specific event for that. You'll need to manually customize each axis title.